# Remove text after second occurrence of space in string

Tags: java

I want to remove text after second occurrence of space in string in Java. Regular expressions should not be used.

Input:

```
String S1 = "VOLKSWAGEN OF SANLEANDRO";
String S2 = "Stack Overflow Site";
String S3 = "Java Learning"; -- there is only one space
```

Output:

```
VOLKSWAGEN OF
Stack Overflow
Java Learning // as there is no second space entire string should be displayed
```

Answer (score 2):

`indexOf(" ");` and `indexOf(" ", firstSpaceIndex);` and `substring(0, end)` would do, see `String` API doc for details

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
String s = "Hello world good bye";
s = s.replaceFirst(" (.*?) .*", " $1");
System.out.println(s);
```

prints

Hello world